# Chrome/Edge browser is not printing the html page properly with absolute position. Print preview is proper

Tags: javascript, html

This is the Html which need to be printed on click of print button in chrome browser . Print preview is coming proper when we try to print in the paper it is printing like below

SANJA BANOVIĆ
.ULOFA PALMEA 13189RSD51,000.00
Banca Intesa AD Beograd-387-000635-1401-387CHDP221720003-21.06.2022 10:13

The absolute position is not showing . in Firefox it is working fine .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
          <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store">
          <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
          <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
       </head>
       <body onload="this.focus();">
          <script src="AdvicePrint.js"></script>
          <DIV class="WNDcontentmodal" id="DIVScrContainer" style="width:22em">
             <DIV ALIGN=CENTER style="clear:both">   
                <input type="button" name="print" id="print" value="Print" onClick="fnPrint()"> 
             </DIV>
          </div>
          <div  id ='divAdvice'class="divAdvice">
             <span class="spanAdviseLabel" style="left:30px;top:22px;position:absolute;">
                <nobr><label class="lblAdvise" name="PAYER_NAME">SANJA BANOVIĆ</label></nobr>
             </span>
             <span class="spanAdviseLabel" style="left:0px;top:44px;position:absolute;">
                <nobr><label class="lblAdvise" name="LBL_catch">.</label></nobr>
             </span>
             <span class="spanAdviseLabel" style="left:30px;top:44px;position:absolute;">
                <nobr><label class="lblAdvise" name="ADDR">ULOFA PALMEA 13</label></nobr>
             </span>
             <span class="spanAdviseLabel" style="left:460px;top:44px;position:absolute;">
                <nobr><label class="lblAdvise" name="PYMT_CODE">189</label></nobr>
             </span>
             <span class="spanAdviseLabel" style="left:513px;top:44px;position:absolute;">
                <nobr><label class="lblAdvise" name="INSTRCCY">RSD</label></nobr>
             </span>
             <span class="spanAdviseLabel" style="left:605px;top:44px;position:absolute;">
                <nobr><label class="lblAdvise" name="INSTRAMT">51,000.00</label></nobr>
             </span>
             <span class="spanAdviseLabel" style="left:20px;top:386px;position:absolute;">
                <nobr><label class="lblAdvise" name="CHKRTIME">Banca Intesa AD Beograd-387-000635-1401-</label></nobr>
             </span>
             <span class="spanAdviseLabel" style="left:302px;top:386px;position:absolute;">
                <nobr><label class="lblAdvise" name="ELECTRONICSTAMP_3"></label></nobr>
             </span>
             <span class="spanAdviseLabel" style="left:300px;top:386px;position:absolute;">
                <nobr><label class="lblAdvise" name="CHKRTIME">387CHDP221720003-21.06.2022 10:13</label></nobr>
             </span>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Below is the java script code

```
function fnPrint() {

 let printElement = document.getElementById('divAdvice');
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT');
    printWindow.document.write(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
    setTimeout(() => { // Needed for large documents
      printWindow.document.body.style.margin = '0 0';
      printWindow.document.body.style.position = "absolute";
    printWindow.document.body.style.display ="inline-block";
      printWindow.document.body.innerHTML = printElement.outerHTML;
      printWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
      printWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
      printWindow.print();
//printWindow.document.execCommand('Print','false','null');
      printWindow.close();
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Why are you copying the HTML to another window? You should just print the current page using a CSS `@media print` media query to hide the bits you don't want to actually print and format it how you need? Then you don't need any fancy JavaScript to print the page and just use the built-in print capabilities. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media. Chrome devtools have media emulation so you can preview the printed page without actually printing

Comment: @phuzi ( tried with media print but still it is having the same problem .  Can you please help me

Comment: I would be tempted to first style the page without absolutely positioning evyerthing.

Comment: @Phuzi, Can you please share me a sample css . I am new to css . Thanks for understanding .